# Why doesn't MSYS grep take options from variable?

Tags: grep, msys

To set my default options for `grep` (from [MSYS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20120426/) in Win7) to ignore object files and specific dirs, I exported 
`GREP_OPTIONS` to `~/.profile` as follows:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--exclude=*.{o,obj,pyc} --exclude-dir={.git,_Output}'
export GREP_COLOR='1;32'
```

Even after restarting the shell for my `.profile` to take effect, my call to `grep` still
searches object files. However, the `GREP_COLOR` variable seems to work. I even tried explicitly setting my options in the same shell before executing `grep`:

```
$ grep --version
GNU grep 2.5.4

Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ export GREP_OPTIONS='--exclude=*.{o,obj,pyc} --exclude-dir={.git,_Output}'
$ echo $GREP_OPTIONS
--exclude=*.{o,obj,pyc} --exclude-dir={.git,_Output}
$ grep $GREP_OPTIONS -r foo .
grep: ./bar.o: Permission denied
./baz.c:My foo text
$ grep --exclude=*.{o,obj,pyc} --exclude-dir={.git,_Output} -r foo .
./baz.c:My foo text
```

How do I get `grep` to automatically use `GREP_OPTIONS` from `~/.profile`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--exclude="*.{o,obj,pyc}" --exclude-dir={.git,_Output}'
```

i.e., enclosing the `--exclude` filename pattern in (double) quotes.

Comment: Thanks, but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the variables in .profile, along with a line that says something like the following:

```
alias grep='grep $GREP_OPTIONS'
```

That just might fix it.